# How to Invoke generic method which returns generic type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection

Really stuck with this problem,

There are `grids` at seperate pages and all of them keeps `List of objects`, all the rows has edit button at the end of the line, and trying to make an dynamic method to return single object when pressed Edit button.

So I add an `generic method` like this (it might be wrong please correct me), just trying to hit the breakpoint in this method thats why includes nothing inside right now

```
public T GetItem<T> (int ID) {
       Type _type = typeof(T);
       object result = null;
       //some code
       return (T)result;
}
```

And the ActionResult calls that GetItem method, ID and TypeName cames from Ajax post, we can assume `ID = 7, TypeName = "ProjectViewModel"`

```
public virtual ActionResult GetEditItem(int ID, string TypeName){
        Type _type = Type.GetType("Project.Models." + TypeName); // returns ProjectViewModel
        Type baseService= Type.GetType("Project.Services.BaseService"); // service that keeps the method
        MethodInfo _method = baseService.GetMethod("GetItem");
        object[] item = new object[] { ID }; // parameter to pass the method
        object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(_type, null); // create instance with that type (ProjectViewModel right now)
        _method.MakeGenericMethod(_type).Invoke(classInstance, item); // invoke it but it returns error in this line
        return View();
}
```

Exception is;

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

Something I miss, what object doesn't match, don't get it. Thanks from now.

Comment: I don't understand... how are the two separate code blocks at all related? there are no calls between them to one another

Comment: My bad, wrong copy/paste. Updated @Kritner

Comment: I think it's something related to the call of generic methods from the client side of a service. Which service technology are you using?

Comment: You have two types: _type and baseService, baseService has method GetName but you call it from the instance of _type.

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad service is just a class name, not a web service. Just added to seperate functions of entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should invoke the method on the type that contains it so this:

```
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(_type, null);
```

Should change to:

```
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(baseService, null);
```

Comment: Well spotted! I'd missed that.